# How to mark DataFrame rows with nan in any column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'd like to use a `DataFrame` with a `DatetimeIndex` to align data from different sets (the columns) on their timestamps.  Each data set may have overlapping and non-overlapping timestamps.  As a simple example

```
import pandas as pd

N = 5
ts_idx1 = pd.date_range('2015-05-22 15:00:00', periods=N, freq='10S')
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5), index=ts_idx1, columns=['a'])

ts_idx2 = pd.date_range('2015-05-22 15:00:20', periods=N, freq='10S')
b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5), index=ts_idx2, columns=['b'])

ab_df = a.join(pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['b']), how='outer')
```

`ab_df` might look something like this

```
                           a           b
2015-05-22 15:00:00    0.293741          nan
2015-05-22 15:00:10   -0.799414          nan
2015-05-22 15:00:20    0.361964    -0.403397
2015-05-22 15:00:30   -0.932385    -0.070403
2015-05-22 15:00:40   -0.702407     0.819322
2015-05-22 15:00:50         nan    -0.771400
2015-05-22 15:01:00         nan    -0.915791
```

Is there a quick way of determining if any `DataFrame` columns contain a `nan` (essentially a set intersection) to determine which are the timestamps or rows that have valid data (non-`nan`) in all columns.   I can think of the following as a possible solution:

```
valid_mask = [np.all(~np.isnan(x)) for x in ab_df.values]
```

but it seems a little cryptic, is there a better way with a `DataFrame` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a somewhat more native approach combining `notnull` and `all`:

```
>>> df.notnull().all(axis=1)
2015-05-22 15:00:00    False
2015-05-22 15:00:10    False
2015-05-22 15:00:20     True
2015-05-22 15:00:30     True
2015-05-22 15:00:40     True
2015-05-22 15:00:50    False
2015-05-22 15:01:00    False
dtype: bool
>>> [np.all(~np.isnan(x)) for x in df.values]
[False, False, True, True, True, False, False]
```

Sometimes it's simpler to use `df.dropna()` rather than materializing a mask, but having an explicit mask can be handy too.